# getting an error while generating ssl certificates

Tags: openssl

On entering the following command on centos terminal,

> openssl rsa -in smtpd.key -out smtpd.key.unencrypted

I am getting the following error,

> Error opening Private Key smtpd.key 3078141676:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such >file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('smtpd.key','r') 3078141676:error:20074002:BIO >routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400: unable to load Private Key

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 6):

The file smtpd.key does not exist in your current directory.

Verify the path you are using, use the full path, or cd to the correct directory.